# Unrecognized plugin: org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm3SMFormatter

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, pom.xml

I am trying to learn about cucumber, unfortunately I need to struggle with configuration problem. Could you help me? I was trying to find solution in web but with no success. Thank you in advance.
I have following error in Intellij when I run feature file:

Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Unrecognized plugin: org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm3SMFormatter
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions$ParsedPluginData.addPluginName(RuntimeOptions.java:372)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.parse(RuntimeOptions.java:125)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.(RuntimeOptions.java:85)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.(RuntimeOptions.java:78)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.(RuntimeOptions.java:70)
    at net.serenitybdd.cucumber.cli.Main.run(Main.java:23)
    at net.serenitybdd.cucumber.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)

[MY_POM_FILE](https://ufile.io/78acp)

Comment: Please ignore this question. I have created pom from the beginning based on some examples I found in net and it is working now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because self answered

Comment: I just updated to Intellij 2018.3.1 and got a similar issue: objc[54340]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10202e4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x1030614e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Unrecognized plugin: org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm3SMFormatter
 at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.addPluginName()

Answer (score 1):

Change CucumberJvm3SMFormatter -> CucumberJvmSMFormatter in your Scenario configurations. It helped me

Comment: Unfortunately this means you need to update each new run/debug configuration. Is there a way to fix this so that new run/debug configurations are created with the correct Formatter plugin ?